# How to get the "root" data in a Blaze template or template helper

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

Let's assume I have to pages which contains the same nested template:

Page1:

```
>rootTeplate
  >fooTemplate
    >barTemplate
```

Page2:

```
>rootTeplate
  >barTemplate
```

How can I write a Template helper which allows me to access the data of rootTemplate in barTemplate? I know I could access the parent context with ../ but in this case the barTemplate doesn't know how many levels it has to go back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be certain of how many levels you want to go back. In a helper in `barTemplate` you can use `Template.parentData`

i.e

```
Template.barTemplate.helpers({
     something: function() {
         var parentDatas = Template.parentData()

         //If there are two levels
         var parentDatas = Template.parentData(2)
     }
});
```

You need to be certain of how many levels you want to get access to and you can plug this number into `Template.parentData`.

If you're not certain of how many levels it needs to go back it may not be worth using this paradigm. Consider using the `data` context from the router or a `Session` hash instead.

Comment: The data context of the router is what I'm looking for. How can I access it inside a template helper function without knowing the root template?

Comment: @MarcS82 Use the `data` param to set it (https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#setting-region-data-contexts) and access it in helpers using `this`

Comment: @MarcS82 Here is an example that shows this: https://gist.github.com/Tarang/847a23b84bc61697e504

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can access the data context from iron:router with Router.current().data().

```
Template.barTemplate.helpers({
  var data = Router.current() && Router.current().data();
  if(data)
    // use it
```